# Segfault when trying to get a byte from memory address

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Im trying to make Sieve of Eratosthenes work with big numbers

The problem I have is that it is giving me a segfault but idk why

It works up until about 100k

But the algorithm works if I replace `cmp byte [rbx], 0` with `cmp dword [rbx], 0`
Im very confused as to why that is happening since all the values in the array are 0's and 1's so a byte should be enough

btw with `cmp dword [rbx], 0` the results are incorrect so I cant use that

X86 64

```
%macro crossOut 4
    xor rdi, rdi     ;edi keeps track of how many numbers were crossed out
                     ;if 0 end loop
    mov rbx, %1     ;array
    add rbx, %2     ;move position to starting index
    mov rax, %3     ;every nth number to be crossed out 

    mov rbp, %4     ; array length
    mov rcx, 0      ;counter
    
    %%loop:
        add rcx, rax
        cmp rcx, rbp
        jge %%exit

        add rbx, rax
        cmp byte [rbx], 0           
        je %%crossout

        jmp %%loop
    %%crossout:
        mov byte [rbx], 1
        inc rdi
        jmp %%loop

    %%exit:
        cmp rdi, 0
%endmacro
```

Comment: Please show your complete code, including how you instantiate this macro.

Comment: here the full code if you still wanna help:
https://github.com/kyopa/assembly-challenges/blob/main/Sieve-of-Eratosthenes/x.asm

Comment: I am not going to look at external sites.  It is your job to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you have.  So please [edit] your question and add all code needed for others to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

See [this CodeReview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277090/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-x86-assembly) for the OP's full program.

---

You are reading past the end of the *numbers* buffer because your code does not take into account the 2nd macro parameter (an offset into the array)!

The first time the offset in the array is 0, and the code will run ok. But later you add to the offset while keeping the array length the same, and so memory that does not belong to the array is addressed.

```
<---- RBP=10 ----->
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

First time RCX allows 4 iterations {2,4,6,8} less than 10:

```
<---- RBP=10 ----->
RBX
v
0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0
    ^   ^   ^   ^
    1°  2°  3°  4°
```

Second time RCX allows 3 iterations {3,6,9} less than 10:

```
  <---- RBP=10 ----->
  RBX
  v
0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,?
        ^     ^     ^
        1°    2°    3°
```

The 3° is past the buffer and, depending on total array length, at some point this buffer overrun will segfault!

The quick fix is to **initialize RCX at the value for the starting index %2** instead of zeroing it.

```
%macro crossOut 4
    xor edi, edi     ;edi keeps track of how many numbers were crossed out
                     ;if 0 end loop
    mov rbx, %1     ;array
    add rbx, %2     ;move position to starting index
    mov rax, %3     ;every nth number to be crossed out 
    mov rbp, %4     ; array length
    mov rcx, %2     ;counter
    
    %%loop:
        add rcx, rax
        cmp rcx, rbp
        jge %%exit

        add rbx, rax
        cmp byte [rbx], 0           
        je %%crossout

        jmp %%loop
    %%crossout:
        mov byte [rbx], 1
        inc rdi
        jmp %%loop

    %%exit:
        cmp rdi, 0
%endmacro
```

A better fix is to establish an absolute last address that you have RBX compare against:

```
%macro crossOut 4
    xor edi, edi   ; EDI keeps track of how many numbers were crossed out
                   ; if 0 end loop
    mov rbx, %1    ; array
    mov rcx, %4    ; array length
    add rcx, rbx   ; Last address
    add rbx, %2    ; move position to starting index
    mov rax, %3    ; every nth number to be crossed out 
    
    %%loop:
        add rbx, rax
        cmp rbx, rcx
        jae %%exit
        cmp byte [rbx], 0           
        jne %%loop
    %%crossout:
        mov byte [rbx], 1
        inc rdi
        jmp %%loop
    %%exit:
        cmp rdi, 0
%endmacro
```

Please notice that

```
    je %%crossout
    jmp %%loop
%%crossout:
```

is better written as

```
    jne %%loop
%%crossout:
```